# How to save selection while sorting column of gridview?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I use gridview to displaying my data. I can choose filters and do sort with every column. But when I change filters and press submit button the sorted column resets to the first column. How could I keep selected column sorted? I tried to use javascript but it still doesn't work as I wanted.

```
let dataSend = $(this).serializeArray(),
            urlSend = $(this).attr('action'),
            method = $(this).attr('method') || 'post';
            if (event.target.id === 'form-match'){
            let getData = '?',
                 sortHref = document.querySelector('#tbl table thead tr .asc') || document.querySelector('#tbl table thead tr .desc');
            dataSend.forEach((obj) => {
                getData += obj.name + '=' + obj.value + '&';
            });
            history.replaceState('List', 'List', urlSend + getData);
            dataSend[dataSend.length] = {
                name: "sort",
                value: sortHref.dataset['sort']
            };
        }
```

This code remembering column, but change sorting type from asc to desc.